# Python - refer to a defined function within a new function

Tags: python

I am trying to self learn Python and in an exercise have defined 3 functions (`c_ground_shipping`, `prem_ground_shipping`, and `drone_shipping`) which each return an integer for a cost of the different shipping methods for delivering a package of a certain weight.

I am now trying to define a new function which will return the cheapest shipping method.

I have written the following:

```
def cheap_shipping(weight):
  if c_ground_shipping < prem_ground_shipping and c_ground_shipping < drone_shipping:
    return "The cheapest shipping method for your package is Ground Shipping. This will cost you £" + str(c_ground_shipping) + " to ship."
  elif prem_ground_shipping < drone_shipping:
    return "The cheapest shipping method for your package is Premium Ground Shipping. This will cost you £" + str(prem_ground_shipping) + " to ship."
  else:
    return "The cheapest shipping method for your package is Drone Shipping. 
This will cost you £" + str(drone_shipping) + " to ship."

print (cheap_shipping(4.8))
```

I am receiving the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 43, in <module>
    print (cheap_shipping(4.8))
  File "script.py", line 36, in cheap_shipping
    if c_ground_shipping < prem_ground_shipping and c_ground_shipping < drone_shipping:
TypeError: unorderable types: function() < int()
```

I assume this is because I am referring to predefined functions within this new one but am not sure how to correct this despite several unsuccessful attempts. If anyone can advise I would appreciate it!

In case you need it, example of one of the three defined functions, `c_ground_shipping`:

```
g_flat_charge = 20

def c_ground_shipping(weight):
  if weight > 10:
    return weight * 4.75 + g_flat_charge
  elif weight > 6:
    return weight * 4 + g_flat_charge
  elif weight > 2:
    return weight * 3 + g_flat_charge
  else:
    return weight * 1.5 + g_flat_charge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you are trying to compare functions, not results returned by function. Eg.

```
if c_ground_shipping < prem_ground_shipping and c_ground_shipping < drone_shipping:
```

should be:

```
if c_ground_shipping(weight) < prem_ground_shipping(weight) and c_ground_shipping(weight) < drone_shipping(weight):
```

Comment: Thank you, but I had tried that too and it also did not work. I thought that might not work as when I then call 'print (cheap_shipping(4.8)) ' I am only defining weight for cheap_shipping. Not sure it that is relevant though if all functions use the variable weight..

Comment: Was it the same error:
    TypeError: unorderable types: function() < int() ?

Comment: So what about to assign values to variables? cgs = c_ground_shipping(weight), pgs = prem_ground_shipping(weight), ds = drone_shipping(weight)?

Comment: if cgs < pgs and cgs < ds:

Comment: No, new error 'TypeError: 'int' object is not callable'. Thank you, I have just realised my mistake. One of my 'functions' was actually just a defined variable and so I have changed to *prem_ground_shipping and c_ground_shipping(weight) and drone_shipping(weight)*. Thank you for your help!